# Launch Youtube Videos using Two Intents in same Webview Activity

Tags: android-intent, webview, youtube, android-webview

I am trying to play youtube videos through the youtube app which are youtube links in my webview,but i have googled it and i am not getting any solution to open or to start an youtube activity forcing me to ask this question

I have tried the below code but it just gets force closed,may be because i have already another intent in my webview.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + video_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

The top code is making my app force close.

My other intent is just working perfectly fine like to play other format of videos which are not related to youtube.

I want my youtube links to play in youtube app,but i am not able to because there is somewhere something going wrong.

Main.java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;



@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class Main extends Activity {


    public final boolean networkCheck() {
        ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
    if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
    connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
        return true;
    } else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

    WebView mWebView;



    ProgressBar loadingProgressBar,loadingTitle;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://..(my webview link goes here).......html");

    loadingProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal); 

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

    // this will be called on page loading progress

    @Override

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

    super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);


    loadingProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
    //loadingTitle.setProgress(newProgress);
    // hide the progress bar if the loading is complete

    if (newProgress == 100) {
    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    } else{
    loadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    }

    });




    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());



    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            List<ResolveInfo> infos = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

            if (infos.size() == 0) {
                // apparently nothing can handle this URL
                return false;
            }

            for (ResolveInfo info : infos) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.android.browser")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });

    if(networkCheck()) {

        // INTERNET IS AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..

        } else {
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myerrorpage.html");

        }
    });
}

    if(networkCheck()) {

        // INTERNET IS AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..

        } else {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Internet Disconnected");
            alertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connection,Enable Internet connection to access the App");

            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            } });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    }
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onUserLeaveHint() {
    finish();
}


}
```

Dont suggest me to use youtube api because i am just not interested in that.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the crash stack trace? It should be available in logcat. I can then refine the answer as necessary. I see a couple of issues with you code as shown though.

1. `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://" + video_id);`
   The scheme for theYoutube URI is not hierarchical, you should remove the `//`.
2. You are setting multiple `WebViewClient` instances that will override each other. Is this really the behaviour that you desire?